# Swift: Combine two map statements into one

Tags: swift

I have to run two `map` statements to turn an array of `String` to `lowercased()` and then `sorted` each element.

`print(["Dollar", "Yuan", "Pesos", "yen", "rupee"].map { $0.lowercased()}.map {String($0.sorted())})`

Output: `["adllor", "anuy", "eopss", "eny", "eepru"]`

Is there a way to combine both `map` into one?

Comment: Absolutely, and you've even already done it once! You've combined `.map{ $0.sorted() }.map { String($0) }` into `.map { String($0.sorted()) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one map in most time:

```
 print(
 ["Dollar", "Yuan", "Pesos", "yen", "rupee"].map{    String($0.lowercased().sorted())}
 )
```

Comment: Eh, sometimes there's value in breaking up big map closures as a series of chained map calls, one per line. You just have to remember to `.lazy` it, or else things might get real slow real quick